# Icon added with CSS :before does not appear on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, icons, font-awesome

I used:

```
td.product-name dl.variation dd li:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f00c";
    color: #000;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

to add an icon `:before` each list element.

The icon appears as it should on **Safari**:

[image]

But not on **Chrome**:

[image]

**Why?**

Here's a link to my website: https://www.mydreamtattoo.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=3981

The check icon list is in the order review table below the product name.

I've used this method to add icons `:before` elements with CSS in the past in other places and it has always worked. This time it didn't.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, you need to add `font-weight: 600;`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found adding `font-weight: 900;` worked.